# How to safely add a timestamp to realm while user is offline & account for device timezone changes?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, realm

When a user answers a question on my app I want to save a timestamp to it. Then when the user connects to internet I can upload the user's progress by filtering realm for questions attempted since the last update & add it to Cloud Firestore.

Before adding the question to Firestore I compare the timestamp of the user's progress for that question if it was uploaded before & if it is newer then update & if it is older then do not update, but instead read the most recent user progress & save it to realm.

I'm thinking of this, because lets say the user changes the time in the phone or uses a different device with a different time when I want the time to be tracked the same so if an update comes from 1 phone/iPad & compared with another phone/iPad that the most recent time stamp is saved both online & to the devices.

Comment: There's some vagueness with this question; it's tagged with both Firestore and Realm; two unrelated databases so we don't know what that implies. Why would you store data in Realm and then upload it to Firebase? That's a lot of extra work supporting two platforms when the task could be handled by one or the other. The second thing is timestamping something when the user is *offline*. The only option there is to use the `Date()` from the device because if they're offline, you obviously cannot get a server timestamp. That means the offline user has control of the time on the device.

Comment: So I use Firebase as a server to store the question database. Then I use realm for when the user is offline & can answer questions. Then when connected to internet again upload their progress to Firestore & download any changes to the database @Jay

Comment: That's a LOT of extra work! Just use Realm for the whole database: it offers both offline and online sync'd storage; much like Firebase. It sounds like your app is offline first and that's where Realm shines. Don't get me wrong, Firebase is an awesome product but simplifying your code = less time developing and debugging and more time making a great app. Again though, *"safely adding a timestamp"* is a bit unclear; if the device is offline, the user can set their time/date to whatever they want and that becomes the timestamp, which is not "safe" IMO. Do you have some code that's not working?

Comment: I think you're right about sticking to just realm. The whole question the timestamps would be if: 1. A user is offline & answers a question on 1st Jan 2. Then goes online & uploads it to the server 3. Logs into another device (maybe upgraded phones or also using an iPad) & then downloads the database 4. Attempts the question offline giving it a new timestamp 2nd Jan 5. Goes online & uploads the change to the server 6. Transfers back to the old device which will compare the timestamp in the offline with what is online & use the newer timestamp @Jay

Comment: All of that sounds perfectly doable. I am not sure the question is answerable though; a device won't know what timezone it's in if it's "offline", and a server generated timestamp cannot be used- there is no way to do what you're asking with this use case. Perhaps the question can be clarified if you present the code you're having difficulty with. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I apologize for the question guidelines on this one... What I gather is because the user is offline the timestamp may be unreliable. Which is why I dont have any code for it because I dont know how it's perfectly doable to ensure an accurate server database with an offline portion...

Comment: I get the question and there are a number of things to consider. If a timestamp is mission critical to the functioning of your app, if you have an offline mode, a guaranteed timestamp accuracy goes out the window and you should limit what a user can and cannot do - for example only write data when online. Perhaps you can remove the reliance on the timestamp all-together and take another approach.

Comment: @Jay Any suggestions on a different approach to track user’s progress while offline if they have more than 1 device?

Comment: The question is a bit vague but it sounds like you're presenting a series of questions to the user that requires them to answer and when they connect to the internet, their answers are uploaded. It's not clear why would would answer a question more than once - could you just record each answer attempt in a List and then upload that list when they connect? That would not prevent them from answering the same question on different devices though, and again, they could change the time on their device so you can't rely on that.